# How to refresh field calculation in live time

Tags: filemaker

I've created a function to calculate time difference between current time and time recorded as StartTime. All calculations are perfect but my "StopWatch" won't update every second. Is there a way of updating it, so it can display every second elapsed since start point?

Window refreshing script isn't an option really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

There is nothing in Filemaker that will happen as a result of merely time passing - except for a script paused for a duration or installed on a timer.

To show a live, ticking clock, your best option would be to use a web viewer - see an example file here: http://fmforums.com/forums/topic/71934-calculating-elapsed-time-realtime/?do=findComment&comment=340205